# How to write "typename typename ..." type scpecifier correctly?

Tags: c++, templates

I have a vector:

`std::vector<std::weak_ptr<SignalFunction>> m_connections`

And then I want to declare a vector of shared pointers to the same type that this vector holds by weak pointer in a generic way:

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<typename typename decltype(m_connections)::value_type::element_type>> validConnections;
```

It compiles fine in Visual Studio 2013, but not in Xcode for iOS. Error:

> expected a qualified name after 'typename'

This, however, works fine:

```
typedef decltype(m_connections)::value_type ValueType;
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<typename ValueType::element_type>> validConnections
```

How can I avoid using the intermediate `typedef`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only need one `typename`. When you write `typename T::some_type::other_type`, the compiler knows that `some_type` must be a type name because it is immediately followed by `::`. Only the last element (`other_type`) must be explicitly annotated, and for that a single `typename` is sufficient.